# Node size / colour by data frame column igraph R

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

So I have networks made up of funders->recipients (first two columns in data frame), made using `graph_from_data_frame(igraph)` in R.

More columns in the data frame include info on donor / recipient type (of institution, uni, gov, ri etc), and total USD invested (integer).

I'd like to colour code nodes/vertices by organisation type, and include size of nodes by total USD.

example of my data frame
'''

```
Donor    Recipient   Recipient.type  Total.USD
NIH         UCLA         Univ           122
WHO         Vax.PLC      Firm           80
Wellcome    LSTHM        Org            104
```

'''

Comment: There a many extant guides that demonstrate how to do this. [This one](https://kateto.net/network-visualization) is comprehensive.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what hasn't worked already.